# Php minimum value form wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

Im trying to get a minimum form value for my Php wordpress form. I want to make that the value is always more than 6. So the visitor have to selected a value above 6 and not below 6. Hope you can help, this is my code so far.

```
<div class="quantity fl-wrap clearfix">
    <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><?php esc_html_e( 'Maanden: ', 'citybook-add-ons' ); ?></span>
    <div class="quantity-item" data-min="1">
        <input type="button" value="-" class="minus">
        <input type="text" name="lb_quantity" value="6" class="qty" size="4" required="required">
        <input type="button" value="+" class="plus">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try using  <input type="number" name="lb_quantity" min="6" class="qty" required="required">

Comment: What has PHP to do with this question?

Comment: Hi there, thank you but i still can't change the value below 6 with the - and +, see attachment: https://imgur.com/a/z9RW6A0

Hope you can help!

Comment: @Advertime What happen when you click + and -. Any error in console ?  Seems more like `javascript` problem.

Comment: @cjmling. Problem is solved with the other answer. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what Wordpress plugin your using.

but try changing following line:

```
<div class="quantity-item" data-min="1">
```

to:

```
<div class="quantity-item" data-min="6">
```

Comment: happy that I could help